# Is it possible to send arbitrary event values ​to a webview?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, I want to create a button on top of a webview, and when that button is pressed, a keyboard event will be sent inside the webview.

There is a property value called javascriptChannels, but it seems that it can only receive signals and cannot send them.

Is there any way to handle this?